MySQL DB design issue for a simple database
Situation: design a simple database for a book collection
Entities:
1. Book table;
2. Author table;
3. Publisher table
4. Imprints table (possibly).

Observations:
1. Books must contain two foreign keys;
    1. Author_ID
    2. Publisher_ID or Imprint_ID

Issues to resolve:
1. Publishers have Imprints;
2. Books bear the Imprint name though the Imprint belongs to a Publisher.
3. How do we handle this issue?;

Since a book will list the Imprint as Publisher, it seems logical that Imprints must be in the Publisher table.  However, a Publisher to Imprints relationship is a one to many relationship.
So there a two questions:

How can we have Imprints tied to Publishers if they occupy the same table?
If Publisher and Imprints are separate tables. how do we know which table to access to get the Publisher as listed in the book?

I tried using an attribute in the Books table to indicate which table to access.  This was not satisfactory to the person for whom I am developing the database.

"This was not satisfactory to the person for whom I am developing the database." - i.e. your database' course TA?

"Since a book will list the Imprint as Publisher," <-- Mistake number 1

Books can have more than one author.  And some books have illustrators or editors in addition to or instead of authors.


Publishers have Imprints

This requirement gives you two choices:

That a Book needs to reference an Imprint, and the Imprint references its parent Publisher.

i.e. Books.ImprintId ➤ Imprints.ImprintId and Imprints.PublisherId ➤ Publishers.PublisherId.


Or a Book needs to reference its Publisher and its Imprint.

i.e. Books.ImprintId ➤ Imprints.ImprintId and Books.PublisherId ➤ Publishers.PublisherId and Imprints.PublisherId ➤ Publishers.PublisherId, such that it's also impossible for a Book to reference an Imprint that doesn't belong to the same Publisher.



Given that not all Publishers have Imprints, and because I'm a fan of composite-keys and I want to spread awareness of the existence of composite-keys to everyone, I propose the latter solution, like so:
(I'm using ISO SQL btw, not MySQL, so you can't just copy-and-paste this into your homework)
CREATE TABLE Publishers (
    PublisherId int         NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    Name        varchar(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Publishers PRIMARY KEY ( PublisherId )
);

CREATE TABLE Imprints (
    PublisherId int         NOT NULL,
    ImprintId   int         NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    Name        varchar(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Imprints PRIMARY KEY ( ImprintId, PublisherId ) /* This is a composite PK */
    CONSTRAINT FK_Imprints_to_Publishers FOREIGN KEY ( PublisherId ) REFERENCES Publishers ( PublisherId )
);

CREATE TABLE Books (
    PublisherId int         NOT NULL,
    ImprintId   int             NULL, /* This is NULLable to accomodate the case when a book has a publisher, but no imprint. */
    BookId      int         NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,

    Title       varchar(50) NOT NULL,

    AuthorId    int         NOT NULL, /* etc */

    CONSTRAINT PK_Books PRIMARY KEY ( BookId ) /* It's up to you if you want Books to have a composite PK or not. */

    CONSTRAINT FK_Books_to_Publishers FOREIGN KEY ( PublisherId ) REFERENCES Publishers ( PublisherId ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Books_to_Imprints FOREIGN KEY ( ImprintId, PublisherId ) REFERENCES Imprints ( ImprintId, PublisherId ) /* The composite FK here makes it impossible to reference an Imprint that doesn't belong to the correct Publisher */

    CONSTRAINT FK_Books_to_Authors FOREIGN KEY ( AuthorId ) REFERENCES Authors ( AuthorId ) /* etc */
);

CREATE TABLE Authors (
    /* an exercise left for the reader */
);


Books bear the Imprint name though the Imprint belongs to a Publisher.

Your TABLE Book wouildn't actually have a column containing ImprintName because that would be a denormalization, and the whole point of using an RDBMS is to have a normalized data store - so instead I assume you mean that your OLAP (reporting, analysis) queries about Books must include the name of their Imprint, which is fine:
SELECT
    b.Title AS BookTitle, 
    a.Name  AS AuthorName,
    p.Name  AS PublisherName,
    i.Name  AS ImprintName
FROM
    Books AS b
    INNER      JOIN Authors    AS a ON a.AuthorId = b.AuthorId
    INNER      JOIN Publishers AS p ON p.PublisherId = b.PublisherId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Imprints   AS i ON i.PublisherId = b.PublisherId AND i.ImprintId = b.ImprintId;

(The Books ➤ Imprints uses LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN to accomodate Books with Publishers but no Imprints).

If Publisher and Imprints are separate tables. how do we know which table to access to get the Publisher as listed in the book?

See above.
